# Django/Selenium : request contains Anonymous user after successfully login

Tags: python, django, selenium, pytest, splinter

I have a set of fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture
def user()
    # A Django user

@pytest.fixture
def browser()
    # Splinter browser

@pytest.fixture
def logged_user(live_server, browser, user)
    browser.visit(url)
    browser.fill('username', user.username)
    browser.fill('password', 'abc')
    browser.find_by_id('login').first.click()
    return user
```

and when I run a test that uses them I got an

```
HttpResponseError: 403 - Forbidden
```

The browser (firefox) executes four actions:

- Visit login page (success)
- Fill login form (success)
- Browser is automatically redirected to an index page (success, user is authenticated)
- Browser visits another page of the site : **Failure**

The body of my test is essentially the following:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)
@pytest.mark.selenium
def test_children_fed_report(live_server, browser, logged_user, page_data):
    url = reverse('app.myview')
    browser.visit(live_server.url + url)
```

The Auth context processor fills user variable with correct value (logged user) except for the last call where it fills with Anonymous user.

Both these answers ([first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537539/django-test-client-returns-an-anonymous-user-after-login), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560432/django-logging-in-as-anonymous-user)) cannot help me: `auth_login` is called and the user is really authenticated before last step.

Thank you in advance for any advice!

Comment: HTTP 403 `access denied`, you should confim whether the user has the permission to visit the page.

Comment: @LittleQ: same behaviour with a user with all needed permissions and with a superuser.